# Calculate the speed needed to pass the roller coaster's inside vertical loop. carriage and people mass is 1000 kg and the radius of the loop is 15m

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

I am a student that really wants to understand how to find answers to questions like this. I would really appreciate someone taking the time to read this and tell me in laymen's terms how to solve this, and what I can improve on so I can practice physics better.

At the top of the vertical loop Fn (nat force) = 0
Fg (gravity force) and x (distance it would take to fall if it stopped at height horizon) are the only ones still to be calculated to find minimum speed , right?

Fn+Fg= MAc (fn = 0)---- M*G = M*v^2/R.

1000 * 9.8 = 9800 ?^2/15
M*G=M^2/R?

V= sqrt 9.8*15? =

V= 12.124 m/s?

Comment: Nat force? You mean normal force? The normal force at the top is not zero (it points downard). You can do this more easily by using conservation of energy to see that your answer isn't correct.